# The one had splurged herself into a top-heavy realist, the other a lopsided romantic

Tags: meaning-in-context

"That is what Mildred Grossman had in common with Holly Golightly. They would never change because they'd been given their character too soon; which, like sudden riches, leads to a lack of proportion: the one had splurged herself into a top-heavy realist, the other a lopsided romantic."

Source: Breakfast at Tiffany's

What is the relationship between one getting suddenly rich and the characteristics of the two characters? And what is a top-heavy realist and a lopsided romantic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ever heard of [*sudden wealth syndrome*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudden_wealth_syndrome)? It refers to the adjustment issues that occur when an individual suddenly gets rich. It leads to a *lack of proportion* in that the sudden riches tend to magnify specific qualities and faults in that individual. These qualities are things like, stress over money, jealousy, stupid decision-making and so on.

Likewise, suddenly being giving their character has led to specific qualities in Mildred Grossman and Holly Golightly to be magnified; realism in the case of Mildred and romanticism in the case of Holly. These qualities have been intensified to such a degree that both characters now appear disproportionate.

[The third definition of *top-heavy* in Merriam-Webster's dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/top%20heavy) is **oversupplied with one element at the expense of others :  lacking balance**. And check out the [second definition of lopsided from Merriam-Webster's dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lopsided). It is: **lacking in balance, symmetry, or proportion**.

So we can conclude that *lopsided romantic* here means that **Holly's romanticism is magnified to the point that it is out of balance, symmetry or proportion with the rest of her personality**. And *top-heavy realist* here means that Mildred's personality has been oversupplied with realism at the expense of other characteristics to the extent of lacking balance.